# Number of occurrences of the digit 1 in the numbers from 0 to n

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have a function:

$f(n)$ = number of occurrences of the digit $1$ in the numbers from $0$ to $n$.

Example: $f(12) = 5$

It is obvious that $f(1)=1.$

Question: Which is the next number for which $f(n) = n$?

Comment: 11111111111111111111111111111111111287981

Comment: Can I write a program to solve it?

Comment: How did you come up with that number?

Comment: Why f(12) is not 4?
1 10 11 12
EDIT: ok I realize that 11 counts double!

Comment: @S4M: count the 1 in 12 as well.

Comment: @S4M: I think f(n) *includes* n. @Mark: Can you give me a little more background before I reveal my secrets? Were you assigned this problem?

Comment: @Isaac: Where did your answer go? I was going to ask for some clarification...

Comment: @The Chaz: Yes, a friend of mine gave me this problem (riddle?). I don't know anything more about it.

Comment: @TheChaz: I thought about it for another minute and realized that it didn't actually prove the result, so I deleted it.  (I'm fairly confident that $f(10^k-1)=k\cdot10^{k-1}$ is correct, but from that and that $f$ is nondecreasing isn't a quick jump to there being no such $n$ other than 1.)

Comment: @Isaac: What about induction on intervals {$10^k, 10^k + 1, ..., 10^{k + 1} - 1$} ?

Comment: @Mark: The number in my first comment was meant to stir the pot; I don't think there is another solution.

Comment: @TheChaz: The problem isn't in extending the result, but rather that knowing $f(10^k-1)=k\cdot10^{k-1}$ for, say, $k=7,8$ doesn't actually imply that there isn't some $10^7-1<n<10^8-1$ such that $f(n)=n$.

Comment: Wouldn't potential solutions to this be more likely/frequent, say, in base 2?  ;-)

Comment: This is a not-so-veiled attempt to elicit a solution to a project euler problem.

Comment: I had seen this problem years ago, had fun with it and sent it to Euler.  Can you prove there are only a finite number of solutions?

Comment: In what base???

Comment: @bol1024: I deleted your answer, which was really a question, and turned it into a comment. Please do not use the answer box to ask question :) You should probably add your "Can I write a program to solve it?" to the body of the original question by editing it or add it as a comment to an answer, if that is more to the point.

Comment: Maybe $n \mod 10^j$ instead of n[j:] ? And what about $d=0$ in $f(0,n) = n$ ? I found solutions $f(d,n) = n$ for $1\le n\le 9$ (OEIS A014778, ...) but nothing for $d=0$.

Comment: Check out [Count the number of Ks between 0 and N?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20945790/2589776).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I dug up my notes on this problem (for those interested this is [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problem [# 156](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=156)) There is an analytical form for the solution to this problem (but alas, even the analytical form is too slow to solve the *big* problem, which requires finding ALL numbers that satisfy this condition for ALL digits 1-9). I will state my result first (to avoid hiding it in the text) and provide explanation for it after.

**SOLUTION**

Define a *list representation* of a number $n$ to be (following a notation I borrowed from continued fractions)

$$n = r_k*10^k + r_{k-1}*10^{k-1} + ... + r_0*10^0 \equiv [r_k,r_{k-1},...,r_0]$$
The function $f(d,n)$ which gives the number of occurances of a digit $d$ up to the number $n$ is given by 
$$ f(d,n) = \sum_{j=0}^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{r_j} (10^j\delta_{i-1,d})+ r_jE(j)  +\delta_{r_j,d}(n[j:]+1)\right)$$

where the notation $n[j:]$ is used to signify the number formed by the last $j$  digits  (e.g. for $n=1234=[1,2,3,4]$, $n[1] = 4$, $n[3] = 234$) and $E(j) = j*10^{j-1}$

Typing this into mathematica (and checking ($f(1,n) = n$ gives the next result of $\mathbf{199981}$).

*NOTE*: This can be generalized even further to any base $B$ by replacing occurrences of $10^k$ with $B^k$

**MOTIVATION**

First observe that in the number  0-9 any digit appears only 1 time.

In the numbers 0-99 any digit appears 10 + 10 times (10 times as the ones digit and 10 times in the range x0-x9)

In the numbers 0-999 any digit appears 20*10+100 = 300 times (20 times in each range of 100+ plus 100 in the range x00-x99)

It is not difficult to prove that this pattern continues, for any number given as $10^k-1$ there are $k*10^{k-1}$ appearances of *any* digit in that range.

This motivates my definition of the function

$$E(j) = j*10^{j-1}$$

However, the number given is unlikely to be as nice as $10^k-1$ we have to learn a clever way to add up the parts of that range. For a number (given in the above notation) like $[4,0,0,0]$. We see that the range $0-999$ occurs 4 times ($0-999$,$1000-1999$,$2000-2999$,$3000-3999$. So we are left with $4*E(3) = 1200$ occurrences of the digit $1$ (this motivates the $r_jE(j)$ term). However, in the range 1000-1999 the digit one occurs an extra 1000 (or $10^j$) times, this extra term only happens if $r_j$ is greater then the digit we are summing over (e.g. if we are adding occurrences of the digit $9$ the answer would be 1200 and not 2200), the best way I could think of to express this conditional statement analytically was with the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{r_j}(10^j\delta_{i-1,d})$

Calculating a number like $[4,1,2,4]$ is not much more difficult, we simply iterate over the sequence $[4,0,0,0]$, $[3,0,0]$, $[2,0]$,$[4]$ following the formula in the previous paragraph. However, the method above will miscount because it ignores the extra occurrence of the digit $1$ in the range $4100-4124$. So at every step of the iteration we have to make sure there aren't any tails that we are forgetting to count, which motivates the $\delta_{r_j,d}(n[j:]+1)$ term.

Comment: Hi ! I was working over this problem 156, and came up with a similar solution (wrote a program) - but i have been struggling to find out HOW to know when to stop.. How does one know that we've exhausted all possible solutions for [f(d,n) - n = 0] ?? My program almost ran out of memory trying to figure out a pattern !!

Comment: Find a simple formula for n=9999999....9. Then note that if you have more than 10 digits you cannot have the desired equality.

Answer (score 6):

Ok this is simple to do with Mathematica.

```
For[i = 0; j = 0, i <= 200000,
 i++, j += (Plus @@ Cases[IntegerDigits[i], 1]); If[j == i, Print[i]]]
```

The result is

```
0,1,199981,199982,199983,...,199990,200000
```

Therefore the number you search has to be 199981.

Comment: While this is a correct way to approach this particular question, the *actual* problem in question (which is a project Euler problem) requires the sum total of **all** numbers that satisfy this condition for all digits 1-10. Not so easy (or fast) do with this brute force method (where do you set the upper search limit for instance?).

Comment: You can easily make it stop after it finds the first wanted number. I leave this modification to you. I agree that with some thoughts you could still fasten up the calculation a lot (factor 100 at least).

Comment: I dont see why 199984, 199985,...,199990 are not solutions as well as we have $f(199984)=f(199983)+1=199984$ and same for every number until 199991.

Comment: You are right I didn't mark properly that I left out the other solutions, now its correct.

Comment: *fasten up the calculation*  I like it.  How about *slowen down the calculation*?

Comment: Seems like it was no correct english :-). I wanted to say "speed up" the calculation in case you didn't get me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the beginning of an idea to solve this. We can start by noticing that $f(10^{n+1}-1)= 1+10^n+10\times f(10^n-1)$ because when you list all the numbers from 1 to $10^{n+1}$ you get: 1... $10^n-1$, $10^n$,..., 1999...99, 20...00,...$10^{n+1}-1$. from  $10^n$ to 1999...99 you can see $10^n+f(n)+1$ the digit '1', and from 20...00 to $10^{n+1}-1$ you get $9\times f(10^n-1)$ the digity '1'. 
So let's call  $u_n=10^n-1$ and $v_n=f(u_n)$.

I can see that $u_9 >v_9$ and $u_{10} < v_{10}$, so the anwswer should be in beetween (or at least smaller than $10^{10}-1$.

Comment: $f(10^{n+1})=(n+1)10^n$.

Comment: hmm that's true.
So $10^{9+1}$ is also a solution.

This problem keeps fascinating me, I want to find ALL the solutions to $f(n)=n$   !

Comment: How many solutions are there to $f(n) = n!$ ?? $$$$ :)